# Reference for the rank of the BN-pair of the finite simple groups of Lie type and not Chevalley

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The rank of the [BN-pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(B,_N)_pair) of a [Chevalley group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type#Chevalley_groups) is the number of simple roots of its Lie algebra, which is the index of the name of its Dynkin diagram ($A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n, E_6, E_7, E_8, F_4,G_2 $).

The finite simple groups [of Lie type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups#Groups_of_Lie_type) and not Chevalley, have also a BN-pair.
*Question*: Is there a reference in which their rank are computed?

*Remark*: the Steinberg group $^2A_3(2^2) ≃ B_2(3)$, so the rank of its BN-pair is $2$ (and not $3$).

Comment: This looks too elementary for this site (and the tag 'lie-groups' isn't relevant).    Keep in mind that the *rank* of a BN-pair is defined to be the rank of the Coxeter system $(W,S)$ where $W:=N/H$ with $H:=B \cap N$ (so the rank is $|S|$ and is easily computed for finite groups of Lie type).

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I know the definition of the rank of a BN-pair. Do you know a reference in which it is computed for every finite simple group of Lie type and not Chevalley?

Comment: You seek the $k$-rank of the non-split connected semisimple groups that are absolutely simple and simply connected (or of adjoint type, if you prefer) over finite fields $k$, since the relative root system has rank equal to the $k$-rank. For each reduced and irreducible Dynkin diagram $\Delta$, the non-trivial elements of the pointed set ${\rm{H}}^1(k, {\rm{Aut}}(\Delta))$ label the possibilities up to isomorphism. Only A$_{n-1}$ ($n>2$), D$_n$ ($n\ge 4$), and E$_6$ admit non-trivial diagram automorphisms, and the $k$-rank is the number of orbits for the Galois action on the absolute diagram.

Comment: The book of Carter called "Finite groups of Lie type" should describe everything in more traditional terms (e.g., special unitary groups for type A, and special orthogonal groups for the unique non-split non-degenerate quadratic spaces of even dimension $\ge 8$ for type D).

Comment: @nfdc23: Is it computed explicitly somewhere? You are talking about the Steinberg groups, isn't it? What about the Suzuki and Ree groups?

Comment: @JimHumphreys I disagree that the question is off-topic here: even if easy (for cognoscenti), I think questions about BN-pairs are something that a PhD student or non-expert mathematician can ask about here; it's certainly beyond the undergraduate curriculum as I know it.

Comment: Yes, look in Carter's book "Simple Groups of Lie Type" (I misremembered the title when I wrote my previous comment).  In particular, see 14.1; the 2nd page of 14.1 specifically addresses the Suzuki and Ree groups (and look in the bibliography too). That book treats all finite groups of Lie type, or rather various things about group of rational points mod the center (to get actual simple groups), but in so doing he works out the BN-pairs for the algebraic groups underlying those examples. There are ways to understand this using more about algebraic groups, but you don't mention your background.

Comment: There are a lot of relevant sources, such as Carter's 1972 book and my more recent one (LMS Lecture Note Series, Cambridge, 2006), as well as Steinberg's 1967-68 Yale lectures: http://math.depaul.edu/cdrupies/research/papers/chevalleygroups.pdf   Or try Chapter 2 of the series of books by Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon (AMS, vol. 40, no 3, 1998): especially 2.3.2, e.g., the  BN-pair ranks of (Weyl groups of) Suzuki and Ree groups are half the Lie rank.    But notation does vary a lot in the sources.

Comment: Concerning the remark, the group in question has two completely different BN-pairs. In one of them B is the normalizer of a Sylow 2-subgroup (because the group is $^2A_3(2^2)$). In the other B is the normalizer of a Sylow 3-subgroup. Both BN pairs  have rank 2. The subscript $3$ indicates that the rank of the BN pair in the overlying algebraic group is 3.